# Multiple constructors won't work

Tags: java, constructor

OK, so I'm trying to learn how to use multiple constructors and can't quite understand why calling these different methods won't work - in fact the first method won't compile.

Thanks for your interest...

```
    // Compile error here. I'm trying to call the 2nd Counter method with default values.
    public void Counter() {
    this.Counter(0, false); 
}

// Here I'm trying to enable a call to the Counter method with integer and boolean attributes in its call.

    public Counter(int startingValue, boolean check) {
    this.startingValue = startingValue;
    this.check = check;
}
```

Comment: Is there a missing `}` ?

Comment: Probably #Nishant but that's caused by sloppy copy and pasting...

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that your first `Counter` "constructor" isn't a constructor at all -- it's a method with a `void` return type.

Make it a constructor by removing the return type.

```
public Counter() {
    this(0, false);
```

Then you can just call another constructor with `this`.

Comment: Well done #rgettman, that seems to compile OK but seems to go against the course notes I'm following. I've a few more changes to make before up-voting your contribution but well received however. My thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use only this(0, false) instead of this.Counter(0, false);

```
public Counter() {
    this(0, false); 
} 

Counter(int startingValue, boolean check) {
    this.startingValue = startingValue;
    this.check = check;
}
```